# python - what does the FOR loop do in this list definition?

Tags: python, for-loop

I don't know Python super well but I know it well enough that I'm trying to translate some Python code to Lua. But I can't figure out what this code is supposed to do.

```
 var_declarations = [
  VarDecl(var_node, type_node)
  for var_node in var_nodes
 ]
```

VarDecl is a class, and var_nodes is a list. Full code is [here](https://github.com/rspivak/lsbasi/blob/master/part10/python/spi.py).

Comment: This is list comprehension. Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: This is a list comprehension syntax, It is instantiating `VarDecl` from var_nodes list

Answer (score 0):

That's called a "list comprehension".  It is exactly the same as:

```
var_declarations = []
for var_node in var_nodes:
    var_declarations.append( VarDecl(var_node, type_node) )
```

It just builds a new list with the result of calling `VarDecl` one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a `list comprehension` syntax. Looking at the code snippet that you referred to, it is instantiating the `VarDecl` class for each `var_node` in `var_nodes` list(array) and creating a new list called `var_declarations`.